# Classify singularities by looking at the limit only

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possibly to determine the type of singularity of $f(z)$ at a point $P$ by only looking at the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ goes to $P$?

I know that $f(z)$ has a pole at P if $\lim_{z \to P} |f(z)| = +\infty$, but I'm not sure how to classify singularities if the limit is not equal to infinity.

I'm especially confused because of the following two examples.

**First example**
\begin{align*}
g(z) &= \frac{z^{2}}{e^{z} - 1} \\
\lim_{z \to 0}|g(z)| &= \lim_{z \to 0}|\frac{z^{2}}{e^{z} - 1}| \\
&= |\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^{2}}{e^{z} - 1}| \\
&= |\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{2z}{e^{z}}| \\
&= |\frac{0}{1}| \\
&= |0| \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Above derivation is my own, so it might not be correct. My book says that the singularity at $z = 0$ of $g(z)$ is an essential singularity.

**Second example**
\begin{align*}
h(z) &= \frac{\sin z - z}{z^{2}} \\
\lim_{z \to 0}|h(z)| &= \lim_{z \to 0}|\frac{\sin z - z}{z^{2}}| \\
&= |\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\sin z - z}{z^{2}}| \\
&= |\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\cos z - 1}{2z}| \\
&= |\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{-\sin z}{2}| \\
&= |\frac{0}{2}| \\
&= |0| \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Again, this is my own derivation. My book says that the singularity of $h(z)$ at $z = 0$ is a removable singularity.

Note that in both examples, the limit approaches 0 while my book says the singularities are different. Their might be a mistake in my derivations or in the book's solution.

Comment: If $p$ is an essential singularity the limit doesnt exists.

Comment: You mean complex $\infty$, not $+\infty$.  Or equivalently $\lim_{z \to P} |f(z)| = +\infty$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point $z_0$ is a removable singularity, then $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)$ exists and is finite. If $z_0$ is an essential singularity, then by the Little Picard theorem, we know that $f$ assumes every complex value within any neighborhood of $z_0$ with at most one exception, so $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)$ doesn't exist.

Riemann's theorem on removable singularities says that if $f$ has a singularity at $a$ and $\lim_{z \to a} (z-a)f(z)=0$, then $a$ is a removable singularity. Let's look at example 1.
$$\lim_{z \to 0} z \frac{z^2}{e^z - 1} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^3}{e^z-1} \\
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^2}{e^z} = 0,$$
so $0$ should be a removable singularity for $f(z)$. What book are you using? I think the solution in the book might be wrong; try looking for errata.

Comment: I updated the question with two examples - the examples seem to undermine your answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the examples you added.

Comment: I'm using "Complex Variables - A Physical Approach with Applications and MATLAB". I already tried looking for errata without luck. You are right, the book must be wrong.